# What is so 'doing' about the modal verbs?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

As far as I have known that verbs are used in the context when a job is done. It is indeed a doing word. What is particularly confusing is how we are using the modal verbs in order to get in touch with a doing sense. Some assistance with the same is most welcome. Most probably I feel I am misinterpreting it in every sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Verbs are the action words** in a sentence that describe what the subject is doing. Along with nouns, verbs are the main part of a sentence or phrase, telling a story about what is taking place. In fact, without a verb, full thoughts can’t be properly conveyed, and even the simplest sentences, such as Maria sings, have one. Actually, a verb can be a sentence by itself, with the subject, in most case you, implied, such as, Sing! and Drive!

> A modal is a type of auxiliary (helping) verb that is used to express: **ability, possibility, permission or obligation**. Modal phrases (or semi-modals) are used to express the same things as modals, but are a combination of auxiliary verbs and the preposition to. The modals and semi-modals in English are:

Can/could/be able to

May/might

Shall/should

Must/have to

Will/would

Ref [Modal Verbs](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/modal-verbs/)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But what is so helping about these verbs?

Comment: **Example** Can/could/may/might/shall/should/must/will/would *you (help me) start the car*... Can you start the car.. Could you wash the dishes...would you watch the baby...shall I pick up the litter.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker and Brad, in modern grammar it is not analysed as "helping" verb, rather it's the main verb of the matrix clause and the other verb that follows it is not included in matrix clause. It is part of the non finite clause that a modal verb takes as Catenative complement. As far as I remember and understood, in traditional grammar the term "helping" has nothing to do with the meaning of the verb. It was used to refer to a syntactic feature; as if the modal verb is helping the verb that comes next to it. In "he might come" it doesn't mean any assistance, but expresses possibility.

Comment: @Man_From_India Thanks for the help As is often the case some of the usage of words in our Language can be hard for beginner's to grasp I am sure that the PO (student) has a much better understanding of the use now, thanks to your comment.